# I want to know how you are doing. / I will want to know how you are doing

Tags: modal-verbs

What's the difference between these sentences in their meaning? Maybe, "will" is used here as modal verb *'to say that someone is willing to do something. You use will not or won't to indicate that someone refuses to do something.'*. But I can't understand the real difference between these sentences. Could you explain it, please? Feel free to provide some examples to explain the good of using "will" here.

> **Keep in touch. I want to know how you are doing.**
>
> **Keep in touch. I will want to know how you are doing.** (Is "will" willing to know here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **will** doesn't mean **am willing** here.

You would say that to someone when parting from them. You know 'how they are doing' **now**, and you ask them to contact you from time to time **in the future** because you will still want to know if they are OK.

Comment: So, that's just Future Simple. Right? But then it sounds awkward if I translate it verbatim into my native language. OK, it seems it's the language difference.